# Azure ACS not forcing to re-authenticate after signout

Tags: wif, acs, azure-active-directory

I have an MVC application that uses Azure ADFS and Azure ACS for authentication. When the user first logs in they are re-directed to Azure ASC to authenticate. When this is done successfully the user is re-directed back to the site with a token and can use the system as normal.

When the user logs out they are re-directed to the signout page and then back to the original login screen. The problem is that when they click the login link again it automatically logs the user in again without requiring them to re-authenticate. This means that it is impossible to change users without closing the browser and if a user leaves the browser windows open anybody can click the login link and log in as that user

My sign-out code is as follows:

```
    public void Logout()
    {
        var fc = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration;
        var signOutMessage = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(fc.Issuer), fc.Realm);
        FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut(signOutMessage.WriteQueryString());
    }
```

and `signOutMessage.WriteQueryString()` generates the following:

```
https://myacsnamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44301%2f
```

Have I configured something incorrectly in ACS, or is my code missing something. I cannot figure out how to stop it automatically re-authenticating the old user

Answer (score 0):

In general, adfs login should require the user to re-authenticate.
However, if the user is logged in to a compuer inside the domain, she is automatically logged in (because she is logged in to active directory).  On a computer outside the domain, the user will need to provide a password, request by the browser 
How would you like to change this behavior ?
[image: example of browser requesting credentials (in dutch)]

Comment: wait, since when does the "computer" pass logged in credentials to the browser? IE does this perhaps, but but I would hope Firefox and Chrome would not.

Comment: Its more like using Windows Authentication on your webserver.  That also happens automagically.  I don't know the *exact* flow of what happens in each case.  I am only certain (because we use it) that it works this way, regardless of the browser. I *assume* some kind of authentication negotiation takes place between server and client.  Inside the domain this is done one way and outside the domain the adfs server switches to http(s) basic authentication ...

Comment: I think you are referring to when Azure ADFS is integrated with the local active directory. This is not the case with our system. The users must log in using the ACS with a username that has no relation to their windows logon.

Comment: Hello, sorry, I think I was on a wrong track.
Several things migth be wrong.  A good thing to do is install a tool such a fiddler to see what happens.  In response to your signout request, the STS (ACS) should send a wsignoutcleanup1.0 message to ADFS and to your application.  You should also review the cookies in your browser to see that all cookies (in your domain, in the acs domain and in the adfs domain) are properly deleted after this call.  This information should then guide you to a solution.